# Get start and end of a selection using javascript

Tags: javascript, selection, getselection

i have an html string like this:

```
<div id="div">Hi how are<span>you?</span> Fine</div>
```

The text will appear `"Hi how are you? Fine"`.

I would like to select a part of the string using mouse and get the beginning and the end
of the selection looking from the full text string.

For example, if i select "you", i would like to obtain start=11 and end=14;

if i select "are you?", i would like to obtain start=7 and end=15.

I wrote this to obtain the selection:

```
function getSel() {
            console.log(navigator.appCodeName);
            if (window.getSelection) {
                return window.getSelection();
            } else if (document.getSelection) {
                return document.getSelection();
            } else if (document.selection) {
                return document.selection.createRange().text;
            }
        }
```

And this code to obtain start and end, but it doesn't work:

```
$("#div").on('mouseup', function(e){
            var text=getSel();
            if(text.anchorNode === text.focusNode){
                var n = {  
                    node: text.anchorNode.parentNode.id,
                    start: text.anchorOffset,
                    end: text.focusOffset
                }
                //selection from right to left
                if(n.start>=n.end) {  
                    var tmp;
                    tmp=n.start;
                    n.start=n.end;
                    n.end=tmp;
                }
            }
            else    console.log("error in selection");          
});
```

Comment: _"but it doesn't work"_. _What_ doesn't work? Are you getting errors in the console, the incorrect output, _no_ output? More information is needed.

Comment: There are no errors in console. Sometimes text.anchorNode != text.focusNode and then i can't get the selection.

Comment: When i get the selection, start and end not seems to be related with the full string and they are not correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector is wrong. `$('#div')` actually selects for any elements that have `id='div'`.

I have made an example of how it's done. If I am not mistaken of what you're trying to achieve.

```
function getSelectionText() {
    var text = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return text;
}

$(function(){
  $("#div").on('mouseup', function(e){
    var thisText = $(this).text();
    var selectedText = getSelectionText();
    var start = thisText.indexOf(selectedText);
    var end = start + selectedText.length;
    if (start >= 0 && end >= 0){
        console.log("start: " + start);
        console.log("end: " + end);
    }
  });
});
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zLms91wn/)**

Comment: The selector is correct, i am testing the code on a div with id div.

Comment: @ScTALE Well, in your question, your `div` doesn't have an id.

Comment: I am using firefox, and getSelectionText() seems not to be defined.

Comment: @ScTALE I have tested the fiddle by using firefox 43 and chrome 47 which work just fine. Which firefox version are you using?

Comment: Firefox 43 on Ubuntu.

Comment: @ScTALE Same then. Can you describe more detail of what you got and how you got it?

Comment: But, your code counts all of the character of the full document: if the #div is set in a bigger html file, i would like to count start and end only from that div and not from the entire html.

Comment: @ScTALE Nope, It just counts start and end only from `#div` and not the entire html.

Comment: um, what if there is more than one appearance of the same text, and you actually select the second appearance? The indexOf will refer to the first appearance and the indexes will not be the correct ones...